# How to start from example diverging REST interface?

Tags: python, openapi-generator, uvicorn

In the uvicorn [exmaple](https://www.uvicorn.org/), one writes `uvicorn filename:attributename` and by that start the server. However, the interface I have generated has no such method `attributename` in `filename`. Therefore, I am unsure what to pass as `attributename`.

## Generated code in main.py

```py
"""
    Somename

    Specification for REST-API of somename.

    The version of the OpenAPI document: 1.0.0
    Generated by: https://openapi-generator.tech
"""
from fastapi import FastAPI
from openapi_server.apis.some_api import router as SomeApiRouter

app = FastAPI(
    title="SomeName",
    description="Specification for REST-API of somename",
    version="1.0.0",
)

app.include_router(SomeApiRouter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute name that you should specify is the name of the variable that holds your FastAPI instance. As they say in the [docs](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-from-the-command-line):

> The ASGI application should be specified in the form path.to.module:instance.path.

In this case for you, it would be `uvicorn main:app` where `main.py` is the file your code is in and `app` is the name of the variable in that file that holds your FastAPI instance.